# Possible to call an additional endpoint after query parameter?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm relatively inexperienced with the Graph API. I have a query returning a user by using the $search query paramter:

`/v1.0/users/?$search="displayName:Test"`

This works as intended. However, ultimately, I would like to get this user's manager. So how do I write the query? I tried adding another endpoint (is /manager called an endpoint?):

`/v1.0/users/?$search="displayName:Test"/manager`

But this throws the error:

**Syntax error: character '/' is not valid at position**

Is it not possible to do that in one call?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call two endpoints.

First endpoint to find the user

```
/v1.0/users/?$search="displayName:Test"
```

It will return the response with user id for the second call to get user's manager

```
/v1.0/users/{userId}/manager
```